# I get 'key is not defined' error when iterating over keys in an object

Tags: javascript, class

Code:

```
class BuildTable {
  constructor(val,tableId,tableBodyId) {
    this.val = val;
    this.tableId = tableId;
    this.tableBodyId = tableBodyId;
  }
  headerRow() {
    const firstDoc = this.val[0];
    const table = document.getElementById(this.tableId);
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');
    const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
    headerRow.classList.add('bg-info');
    for (key of Object.keys(firstDoc)) {
      const th = document.createElement('th');
      const thText = document.createTextNode(key);
      th.appendChild(thText);
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
    }
    thead.appendChild(headerRow);
    table.appendChild(thead);
  }
}
```

I'm able to iterate over the keys using `for loop` just fine when not using within class objects. Also, I'm able to `console.log(firstDoc)` and it spits out fine. Is there a limitation or is `key` a reserved word within class objects?

Comment: `key` is not a reserved word. However, your `key` variable definitely should be declared with `let` or `var`.